# Set Background in ListView Item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Hello i have custom ListView Adapter.
I try to set background image , but i cannot set the height of each item.
In each item i have this following xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listMenuItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nasi_goreng">

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Menu Title -->
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/menuTitle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
         android:textSize="@dimen/menuTitle"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Post Date -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/menuTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/postDate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result is like this :

[image]

**Update :**
here is my ListView xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

List Selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" ></item>

</selector>
```

How to fix height??

Thank you

Comment: can you put listview xml file?

Comment: Please check my question. I have been updated.

Comment: can you put listselector xml?

Comment: Please check my question again.

Answer (score 1):

Design the background image according to your need. Decide the size(width & height) of list item and design an image of that size and then use it as background image. If you want to use this app in tab also then design image in multiple size (according to android image scaling)

Read this link (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

**Following are the required guidelines for image resource.**

Note: For other screen density android prefers hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi.

So we may consider scaling ratio as 2:3:4:6:8 for each icon and image.

- mdpi : 2x (baseline)
- hdpi :  3x
- xhdi : 4x
- xxhdi : 6x
- xxxhdpi : 8x

Comment: But how about width? Because in every device have different width.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see and try it. Please accept the answer if it help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **RelativeLayout** **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** instead of **android:layout_height="80dp"** if its not worked for you

Please post your excepted result

May be the problem comes from your list selector can you post your list selector

Comment: Please check my question.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of setting background image on normal view is not very good. This relativelayout has conflict when drawing this image with its fixed height.If you want to show this image with better performance, you should add a ImageView to this layout.

Comment: Can i attach another text above `imageView`?

Comment: it mean we should not add background to parent layout ?

Comment: @fanjavaid You can do that in a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.It makes the ImageView just like the TextView's background.

Comment: @SilentKiller In my opionion, it won't bother if it is just a color or 9 patch resource. But if zoom of image is needed, you'd  better to use a ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_width & android:layout_height should be specified in dp's in this case, otherwise it will take as much space as the background image needs...

Comment: It seems, listview doesn't honour this kind of specification. It takes as much space as it requires....

you can try specifying dp for each item instead of the layout itself, if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 0):

here's an example from androidhive which works as it is expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/sharebutton" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:textColorLink="@color/link" />

        <info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

see the profilepic section. it's size i.e, height and width both are fixed and it works...

so how about isolating the imageview with a different layout with fill_parent and wrap_content params while the imageview params are fixed to dp's